# Laravel 5.2 index route fails to load but other routes work properly on sharehosting

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

My Laravel 5.2 project works well on localhost, but when I move to production share host server all routes work except the root route for index.blade.php.

For example when I try to access www.xxx.com it shows **The xxx.com page isn’t working,  xxx.com is currently unable to handle this request ERROR 500**

But when I do www.xxx.com/signup the page load. The common fix I see around is for when www.xxx.com works while other routes fails to load. Any hint or assistance to resolve this issue is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the fix for this issue. The controller that handles www.xxx.com

```
    Route::get('/', 'AuthController@index');
```

Calls three tables like this

```
Public function index(){
    $result_set = Authuser::all();
    $result_set2 = Examcreator::all();
    $result_set3 = Examcreatorbrag::all();


    $userData = array();

    $userData['totalusers'] = count( $result_set);
    $userData['exams'] = count( $result_set2) + count( $result_set3);

    return View::make('index', compact('userData')); }
```

The tables rows got large with time and causes the page to throw error 500 because I use Model::all(). When I discover that, this was the issue I refactor the code in a more efficient way like this.

```
public function index()
{
    $result_set = Authuser::where('id', '!=', 0)->count();
    $result_set2 = Examcreator::where('id', '!=', 0)->count();
    $result_set3 = Examcreatorbrag::where('id', '!=', 0)->count();

    $userData['totalusers'] = $result_set;
    $userData['exams'] = $result_set2 + $result_set3;

    return View::make('index', compact('userData')); }
```

The laravel code works on localhost because the rows in table are few and fail on life sharehosting server because the rows are large. Using Model::all() takes little bit of caution when the table rows is large. These changes fixed the issue